# How to transfer information from MainActivity to a custom adapter

Tags: android

I have a main activity with an edit text, button, and a custom listview. The custom listview contains a textview(and other views) to display what is entered in the edit text after the button is pressed. However, I'm not sure how I would transfer the information from my main activity to my custom adapter in hopes to update one specific textview. If there is a more efficient way to complete my task, please share it. I'm new to android studio so any knowledge would be great.

I've tried calling on a method in MyAdapter such as

```
public void updateExerciseNames(String name) {
        exerciseNames.add(name);
        counter++;
    }
```

(updates an arraylist with strings that should appear on a textview and then the textview is updated.)

Creating a getString method in my Main_Activity that retrieves the string required.

Using an intent.

This is what my custom adapter looks like

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private Context context;
    private TextView list_txt;


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> records, Context context) {
        super(context, 0, records);
        this.list = records;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_custom, parent, false);
        }

        Button list_but=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_but);
        TextView list_txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById((R.id.list_txt));
        list_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                list.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: `private ArrayList<String> list;` Make that public. Then you can change any string from main activity with `adapter.list.set(position, editText.getText());` Dont forget to notify data changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using another constructor like the one you made

```
MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> records, Context context,YOUR_DATA_TYPE your_data)
```